# Media Foundation panorama (equirectangular) video playback in C++

Tags: c++, direct3d, ms-media-foundation, dxva

I've been trying to figure out how to playback a video file that is equirectangular (and adding movement controls.) I got the playback part using SDK samples. However, getting the video frames to texture to add to a skybox seems downright impossible. I've already looked at the custom EVR and DX11 renderer but can't seem to understand how all that works. Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think it possible to implement you idea, but you must know that all default renderers are used for simple renderer video. However, you can write own implementation IMFMediaSink class for your purpose. Or use simple frame grabber. You can get more by link - [videoInput](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/776058/Capturing-Live-video-from-Web-camera-on-Windows-an). It web site contains code for grabbing live video frames from web cam and rendering them via texturing of square object in OpenGL - very similar of your need.